# Identify book, Gigantic Fleets of Ancient Aliens

Tags: story-identification

In a Star Trek paperback, a description for an upcoming or in-print book was given and I long ago forgot the title.  I'm fairly certain this promoted book is also a Star Trek book.

The premise is that millions or billions of years ago, two great civilizations, each composed of thousands of alien species, clashed in a gargantuan war.  It described how the first encounter was between equally massive fleets of at least 100,000 ships (maybe more).  Despite one of those fleets being a **recon** fleet, the sheer scale of both civilizations meant the war dragged on for quite a while (I don't remember how long).  If this was a Star Trek novel, then there was some danger, or maybe a lost fleet or something, that was causing trouble or had the potential to cause trouble for the TNG crew and the rest of present galactic civilization.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Could either be from the one of the *Invasion!* crossover books or *Dujonian's Hoard*.